# Probability over $\Bbb R$ and density

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Let $P$ a probability over $(\Bbb R, \mathcal B)$ where $\mathcal B$ are Borel set, $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $f\geq 0$  almost everywhere s.t. $\forall a<b$ rational
> $$P([a,b]) = \int_a^bf(x)dx$$
> This implies that $P$ has $f$ as a density function.

---

$f$ density function for $P$ means that $f:\Bbb R \to [0,\infty)$ borel measurable function and
$$P(A) = \int_Af(x)dx $$
for all $A$ borelian sets.

---

I know a characterization that

$$\boxed{f \ \text{density for some} \ P\iff \int_\Bbb R f(x)dx =1}$$

---

For $P$ to admit $f$ as density $f$ should be a density so
$$\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)dx 
= \int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx+ \int_{-\infty}^0f(x)dx \\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx+ \int_{-n-1}^{-n}f(x)dx \bigg)\\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (P([n,n+1])+P([-n-1,-n]))\\ 
=P[0,\infty) + P(-\infty, 0] = P(\Bbb R) =1$$
So $f$ is a density for some probability over $\Bbb R$. Now (supposing what I've done right) I wold like to use cumulative distribution function to prove that $f$ is $P$'s density, but I'm not very sure on how to proceed, thank you for the help!

Comment: What is the definition of $f$ being a density of $P$?  I think you should write the definition first.

Comment: @geetha290krm edited. You want me to write the definition because there are many definition of density or because I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Use standard measure theoretic arguments. Prove it when $A$ is a disjoint union of half closed intervals and then use Montone Class Theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm I'll give it a shot, so first part is an acceptable answer?

Comment: @geetha290krm I try your suggestion: if I prove that the relation holds for half closed sets then I can extend the probability to Borel $\sigma$-algebra since half closed set generate Borel $\sigma$-algebra, but how do I prove that on half closed set, could you elaborate further?